# How to get grouped columns count by value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, pivot

hello I have table where is one column jtypeid (14 is activity | 12 is exam) and studentid

I want to get count of activity and count of exam as column. my query is

```
SELECT name,surname, count(jtypeid) as activity 
FROM lms_journal INNER JOIN 
     lms_student 
     ON lms_student.id = lms_journal.studentid 
WHERE lms_journal.jtypeid=14 
GROUP BY studentid 
UNION 
SELECT name,surname, count(jtypeid) as exam 
FROM lms_journal INNER JOIN 
     lms_student 
     ON lms_student.id = lms_journal.studentid 
WHERE lms_journal.jtypeid=12 
GROUP BY studentid
```

for example

```
id jtypeid studentid
1    14       100
2    14       101
3    12       100
4    12       101
5    14       102
6    14       100
```

result should be:

```
studentid exam activity
100       1       2
101       1       1
102       0       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with conditional aggregation

```
select studentid, 
       count(case when jtypeid=12 then 1 end) as exam,
       count(case when jtypeid=14 then 1 end) as activity
from tablename
group by studentid
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    studentid,
    sum(jtypeid = 12) exam,
    sum(jtypeid = 14) activity
from lms_journal
group by studentid
```

Expression `sum(jtypeid = <n>)` takes advantage of the fact that, in MySQL, a true condition is evaluated as `1` in numeric context, and a false condition is evaluated as `0`. This makes the query shorter and somehow more readable (if you know the trick).